# Print occurrences of elements in an array list

Tags: java

I need two input array A and array B.
The answer will be like this - if input A is

```
{5,2,6,8}
```

and input B is

```
{6,5,5,8,5,6}
```

then the output will be:

```
2 (0 times), 5 (3 times), 6 (2 times), 8 ( 1 times)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a [tour] and read [ask]. In advance, I'll tell you this: SO is _not_ a "write my code" site, i.e. _you_ have to show some effort, especially some code and how you've already tried to solve your problem, otherwise the question will receive downvotes and is very likely to get closed.

Comment: And be clearer what you want to achieve. As I understand you want to count the occurences of the elements of A in B.

Comment: convert the ArrayList into  an array,and use counting sort technique on it.Next time please show us what you have tried or what problems you were facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can achieve it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A={5,2,6,8},
            B={6,5,5,8,5,6};
    int[] count = new int[A.length]; // An array counting the occurences
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(); // The String to be displayed. StringBuilder is better than String, when multiple concatenations occur.

    Arrays.sort(A); // Sorts array A in ascending order (by default).

    // This loop counts the occurence of each value of A inside B
    for (int i = 0; i <A.length; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < B.length; j++){
            if (A[i] == B[j])
                count[i]++;
        }
        // After each value of A, add the number of occurence in the String
        result.append(A[i]).append(" (").append(count[i]).append(" times), ");
    }


    // Displays the String in the console, removing the last ", "
    System.out.println(result.substring(0,result.length()-2));

}
```

Comment: Thank for your advice, i will try this and feedback ^^